# How to change the color of navigataionbar once we turn from landscape to portrait mode and vice varsa in IPhone

Tags: iphone

Hi Will some body help me

I am using 3.2.5 SDK and 4.2 ISO 
Now I am creating a splitViews project but here I am facing problem my problem is that once i am in portrait maid and move other class then i change my portrait mode to landscape at that time my rootview navigation bar color has change But i did not want to change previous i made its green color but after shifting portrait mode to landscape its change please help me some one.

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass UISplitViewController, and override the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method.  For example:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
       [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        self.masterNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;
    } else {
        self.masterNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(7.0/255.0) green:(140.0/255.0) blue:(170.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
    }

    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but my issue is once i am in portrait mode and without click on barbutton on detailview navigation bar if i rotate from protrait to land scap or landscap to portait it fine but once i m click in barbutton in detaiview on portrait mode then i rotrat from portrait to land scap at that time my navigation bar color has changed that i don't want please help in this sichation

Comment: My problem in splitview once i stand in Portrait mode and after that if i click on barbutton on top of detailview and then i rotrat to landscap then its color is changing if i m not clicking on barbutton then i m moving its not changing its working fine plz help